# Proper locking in method calls

Tags: python, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm talking to a measurement device. I basically send commands and receive answers. But I'm providing a method `ask` that sends a command and reads back the answer. If I lock this method I get a deadlock due to the called methods `read` and `write` locking aswell. If I don't lock another thread could steal the answer or write before I'm reading. How would you implement this?

```
import threading

class Device(object):
    lock = threading.Lock()
    def ask(self, value):
        # can't use lock here would block
        self.write(value) # another thread could start reading the answer
        return self.read()

    def read(self):
        with self.lock:
            # read values from device

    def write(self, value):
        with self.lock:
            # send command to device
```

Comment: Congratulations, you just discovered one of the things STM proponents talk about when saying "locks don't compose".

Comment: Shouldn't that be `lock = threading.Lock()` with parenthesis?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Ups, my bad. Fixed it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`threading.RLock()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#rlock-objects) to avoid contention within a single thread:

> A reentrant lock is a synchronization primitive that may be acquired
>   multiple times by the same thread. Internally, it uses the concepts of
>   “owning thread” and “recursion level” in addition to the
>   locked/unlocked state used by primitive locks. In the locked state,
>   some thread owns the lock; in the unlocked state, no thread owns it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threading.RLock() object to do reentrant lock. But t is better to rewrite code such way, it do not need RLock. For example you could remove locks from write(), read() and rewrite ask() similar way

> ```
>     with self.lock:
>         self.write(value)
>         r = self.read()
>     return r
> ```

RLock() in old versions of python  work slower, because it is more complicated in implementation.

Also note, in code you wrote, you get one lock for all instances. In some cases it is appropriate (for example if you have only one device and many instances), but in general not. If you want different locks for different instances, put its initialization in __init__() method.